# MDS error when renaming attribute

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, master-data-services

I am trying to rename attribute name from 'BRANCH _CODE' to 'BRANCH_CODE' (get rid of that space) at MDS, and I'm getting the following error:

**Cannot alter the view 'viw_SYSTEM_2_34_CHILDATTRIBUTES', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

The according user is a 'sysadmin' and 'dbowner' of MDS database. Has anyone ever faced this problem?

Comment: Sh!t, I remember that one but I really CAN'T remember how exactly did I solve it. I remember something though, somehow columns need to be refreshed because at one moment MDS looses connection with underlying schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.
It was the SQL security issue. Someone somehow changed the security settings of MDS SQL user "**mds_schema_user**". I made him the owner of the following schemas of MDS DB:

- mdm
- mdq
- stg
- dqs
- db_owner

It worked well for me.

Comment: I had a similar error message trying to delete an Entity. The suggested changes to mds_schema_user had no effect.  I found the service account used by IIS to run the Application Pool for MDS, and gave that account the db_owner Database Role (temporarily).

Comment: FWIW I've created a Connect Bug Report for this issue - please vote if you have struck this also: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/954858/mds-deleting-entity-error-cannot-drop-the-view